# Anchor element does not start download for some URLs

Tags: javascript, html, azure-blob-storage, anchor

Firstly, I know that this has been asked, but no threads reflected my issue.

Maybe I am foolish for thinking it's somehow different, but I'll give it a shot:

I have anchor element, that is hidden and used just to download files, given by download URL. The download URL comes from backend and points to one of two blob storages (in two different domains, both different than the website).

From what i have read, browser prevents downloading file from external domains and so, it tries to open them in new tab. This is exactly what I am observing.. to some degree.

But, if I get link from blob storage A - it opens in new tab (very bad), BUT if I get download URL from blob storage B it downloads just fine.

I am using `download` attribute on my anchor element.

Any ideas why this behavior is so inconsistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that the issue was with how we generated links for one of our blob storages, it lacked content disposition.

In order for this link to start downloading file correctly we need to set the content disposition on the blob. I am using nuget `Azure.Storage.Blobs` and method `GenerateSasUri` to get download URL. There I set property `ContentDisposition` on `BlobSasBuilder` object, that is passed to the method.

Roughly, the code looks like:

```
var blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder(/*some params*/);
blobSasBuilder.ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"{myFileName}\"";
// other setup

var downloadUri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(blobSasBuilder);
```